# Why does s[n..-1] work in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm fairly new to ruby. Recently, I wanted to extract a portion of a string from the n'th character of said string to the end.

Doing something like s[n,(s.size - n)] seemed pretty inelegant to me, so I asked a couple of friends.

One suggested I try s[n..-1], and sure enough that works, but he couldn't give me a good reason why it should work. I find the fact that it works rather puzzling, as the following output from irb1.9 should explain:

```
> s = "0123456789"
=> "0123456789"
> s[2..-1]
=> "23456789"
> (2..-1).to_a
=> []
```

So as you can see, the range object 2..-1 is empty -- it has no members, which is absolutely what you expect if you go upwards in value from 2 to -1. This is consistent with the documentation for how range objects should work.

The documentation for indexing a string with a range clearly says: "If given a range, a substring containing characters at offsets given by the range is returned" -- but that is an empty set.

I also can find no examples in "The Ruby Programming Language" or in the Ruby docs in which a string is indexed using `s[n..-1]` or the like, and can find no examples of it in other official sources. It appears to be folklore, however, that it works even though nothing in the manuals indicate that you can index a string with a range this way, and get the result you get even though the range has no members.

Yet, my friend was correct, it works.

So, could someone please explain *why* this works to me? I'm also very much interested in knowing if the fact that it works is a fluke of MRI/YARV or if this is absolutely expected to work in all Ruby implementations, and if so, where is it documented to work?

EDITED TO ADD:

An answerer below claimed that only the range's `begin` and `end` attributes matter for these purposes, but I can find no documentation of that in TRPL or in the Ruby documentation. The answer also claims that there are indeed examples of such "mixed-sign" range indexing, but the only one I could find was in a context where the mixed-range index was shown to produce `nil`, not a slice of a string. I therefore don't find that answer satisfying.

EDITED TO ADD:

It appears that the correct answer is that this is indeed a defect in the Ruby documentation.

EDITED TO ADD:

The bug was fixed by the Ruby documentation team: see https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6106

Comment: Array#[] is a method. Googling for `ruby string []`or `ruby string#[]` will lead you to the docs as top result.

Comment: Sorry, but no. That's not correct. I've already read that documentation. You need to re-read the question much more carefully.

Comment: a[-3,2]                #=> "er"
a[-4..-2]              #=> "her"
a[12..-1]              #=> nil
a[-2..-4]              #=> "" (quoting from the docs)

Comment: You've again misunderstood. I was well aware of the section of documentation you are quoting and it is _not_ a counterexample. Please read the entire discussion before commenting, including everything below. Note that the only example you quote above that is relevant from the docs is `a[12..-1] #=> nil` and that yields `nil` and not a string slice -- no examples of what I'm talking about exist in the docs, and yes, I'm certain of that.

Comment: +1 I never thought about this before.

Comment: In some languages indexing an array with negative numbers indexes from the end. so a[-1] is the last element, a[-2] is the second to last, etc. Sounds like ruby picked up a bit of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the documentation.

Ruby's documentation has sucked since the Pickaxe book descended like a meteor on matz's actually correct and comprehensive HTML doc. This is a subject that still irritates me on occasion. The answer to your question, from 1.*4*: [link](http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/html/ruby/Array.html)

> self[nth]
>
> Retrieves the nth item from an array. Index starts from zero. If index is the negative, counts backward from the end of the array. The index of the last element is -1. Returns nil, if the nth element is not exist in the array.
>
> self[start..end]
>
> Returns an array containing the objects from start to end, including both ends. If ... is used (instead of ..), then end is not included. if end is larger than the length of the array, it will be rounded to the length. If start is out of an array range , returns nil. And if start is larger than end with in array range, returns empty array ([]).

-1 is the last index of an array by definition, as a convenience.

Comment: Okay, so this then used to be documented and is now part of the folklore because the documentation fails to mention it currently -- do I have that right?

Comment: (And how might one go about filing a bug report about this... I haven't been able to figure that out.)

Comment: @Perry, sure. Just like [this](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3712114), I suppose.

Comment: A better link would have been http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/ -- I have now filed a bug report.

Comment: @Perry FWIW both ruby-doc and apidock explicitly state that the -1th element is the last element.

Comment: @DaveNewton: You have missed the point. It isn't about negative indexes. It is about ranges with mixed sign, esp. when the start is positive and the end is negative, and their use in array and string slicing.

Comment: @Perry Yeah, I don't think I did--positive indices start from the beginning of the string, negative indices start from the end, as documented. I don't really see how having start/end indices with mixed signs changes that.

Comment: Because we're not dealing with indices. We're dealing with range objects. Note that ranges are individual objects -- they are not a fancy indexing notation. The fact that an empty range will none the less return a slice is an unexpected event -- handy, sane, but unexpected. @JulianFondren understood the question.

Comment: I didn't know there was HTML documentation by Matz for Ruby. +1!

Answer (score 2):

You're right that the range `n..-1` is empty. However that doesn't matter because `String#[]` doesn't treat the range as a collection - it just uses the range's `begin` and `end` attributes.

Regarding documentation: [The rdoc documentation of `String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) lists the behavior of `String#[]` for every possible type of argument (including ranges with negative numbers) with examples. So you don't have to rely on folklore. Relevant quote:

> If given a range, a substring containing characters at offsets given by the range is returned. [...] if an offset is negative, it is counted from the end of str.
>   [...]
>
> ```
> a = "hello there"
> # ...
> a[-4..-2]              #=> "her"
> ```

Comment: But where is the bit about only `begin` and `end` mattering documented? Also, the bit about offsets does not explicitly tell us that an empty range object is okay because the `begin` and `end` attributes are all that matter, and no examples of this sort of mixed sign indexing are given in any document I've seen. Note that the `a[12..-1]` above produced `nil` in context, not a slice of the array.

Comment: You edited your example above to remove the `a[12..-1]` example producing `nil` rather than an array slice. So far as I can tell, your claim is not true: there isn't "every possible type of argument" in the document, and for this, one _does_ have to rely on folklore.

Comment: @Perry It produced `nil` because the `12` is out of bounds for the given string. Note that `-4 .. -2` is an empty range, too, so that example shows you that empty ranges are not a problem (plus if they were, ranges using negative indices would never work).

Comment: Yes, precisely, it produced `nil`, but why it produced nil was entirely ambiguous. -4..-2 is not an empty range -- you're totally wrong on that. Try (-4..-2).to_a

Comment: @Perry The two sentences I quoted tell you all you need to know. There is no need for conjuncture. The documentation doesn't say that mixing positive and negative integers is allowed because there's no reason to assume it isn't in the first place.

Comment: Let me be direct here: you don't seem to actually know an answer to this question. Please let someone else answer it.

Comment: @Perry Nothing ambiguous about it. In the part that I didn't quote, the docs clearly say that you get nil if (and only if) the index is out of bounds, which is the case here.

Comment: You just claimed that -4..-2 was an empty range, too. Please show me in the documentation where it says that only the `begin` and `end` attributes matter for range based indexing of strings or please allow someone else to answer the question.

Comment: @Perry You're right, I was wrong about that. Obviously I can't count to 0. Mea culpa. I still think there's nothing in the docs to indicate that empty ranges would be a problem, so there's no reason to assume they are.

Comment: I didn't say the docs indicate that empty ranges are a problem. What they don't say is that they're not a problem and that only `begin` and `end` for the range count for the string index operation. Nothing in the docs says that `s[3..-1]` should not work -- the issue for me is that nothing actually indicates in any way that it should work, either.

Comment: Actually, let me correct that slightly: it is ambiguous whether the docs indicate that an empty range should always produce a `nil` result. You could read it either way. It appears that this is not the intended reading, of course.

Comment: @Perry It's cool to disagree with someone and/or tell them they're wrong, but repeatedly telling them to "let someone else answer the question", strikes me as a poor approach.